# Как можно ограничить результаты выдачи плагина autocomplect?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Использую плагин для авто заполнения utocomplect. Мне нужно ограничить выдачу до 5 результатов(не саму выдачу а количество формируемых плагином тегов) То есть нужно ограничить выдачу которая попадает в dom. В самом плагине не нашёл как это можно сделать . Кто сталкивался подскажите как решить ?

Вот мой код:

```
$("#myinput").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var term = $.trim(request.term);
        var reg = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
        if (term !== "") {
            response($.grep(projects, function(tag) {
                return tag.label.match(reg);
            }));
        }
    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $("#myinput").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#myinput").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#myinput-id").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#myinput-description").html(ui.item.desc);
        $("#myinput-icon").fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/" + ui.item.icon).fadeIn('slow');
        });

        return false;
    }
})
```

Весь код чтоб было понятно о чём я толкую(нужно ввести букву "л") : http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/74/

Comment: Вот тут есть подходящие решения - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617373/limit-results-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр source может быть не только Array, но и Function, в этой функции есть два аргумента -

```
source: function(req, cb) { 
    ищем req.term среди данных, формируем list
    фильтруем list
    cb(list);
}
```